# Multiprocessing in python of function with positional and keyword arguments that returns a value

Tags: multiprocessing, keyword-argument

I would like to learn how to parallelize a function that effectively consists of a single for loop. This function accepts both positional and keyword arguments.  This function returns a 1D-array each time that it is called. I would the parallelization to affect only the positional argument, but have the freedom to vary the keyword arguments as needed.

Below is the MWE.  I am trying to parallelize the for-loop of the `my_func_serial()` as `my_func_parallel()`. N.B., in my setup, the function `my_func_parallel()` would be found in a separate `src` file from `main`.  So, I would have `main_program.py` that imports `my_func_parallel()` from `src_program.py`.  This way, I can write other python scripts that would call `my_func_parallel()`.  Note: the mathematical operation found in `my_func_serial()` and `my_func_parallel()`is arbitrary and has no other context here.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from itertools import repeat


alpha = 3
beta = 5
charlie = 7

N = 10
# N = int(1e6)

def my_func_serial(ii, a = 1.0, b = 2.0, c = 3.0):

    f = np.zeros(3,)

    for mm in range(3):
        f[mm] = (ii * (a + b + c)) / (mm + 1)

    return f


def my_func_parallel(ii, a = 1.0, b = 2.0, c = 3.0):

    f = np.zeros(3,)

    for mm in range(3):
        f[mm] = (ii * (a + b + c)) / (mm + 1)

    return f    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    tstart = timer()

    P = np.zeros((N, 3))

    for nn in range(N):
        P[nn] = my_func_serial(nn, a = alpha, b = beta, c = charlie)

    telapsed = timer() - tstart
    print('  serial function done, elapsed time: %0.16f' % telapsed)

    # processes = mp.cpu_count()
    processes = 4

    p = mp.Pool(processes)

    tstart = timer()

    M = p.starmap(my_func_parallel, zip(range(N), repeat(alpha), repeat(beta), repeat(charlie)))

    p.close()
    p.join()

    M = np.array(M)

    telapsed = timer() - tstart
    print('  parallel function done, elapsed time: %0.16f' % telapsed)
```

Output is:

```
  serial function done, elapsed time: 0.0000336770000000
  parallel function done, elapsed time: 0.1101100360000000
```

Ultimately, the numpy arrays, P and M, should both be $N \times 3$ arrays and should be equal.

My questions:

1. Shouldn't the parallel version of `my_func()` run (much) faster than the serial version?
2. I only want to 'parallelize' the positional argument of `my_func_serial()` and not the keyword arguments. In other words, all that changes in each iteration of `my_func_parallel()` is its positional argument. Given that I also want to access the array that is returned by the parallelization, have I selected the appropriate multiprocessing class to use, e.g., `starmap()`?
3. Is there a 'better' way to do this than via itertools and `repeat()`?
4. Is the line `M = np.array(M)` necessary? Why?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: It's been three weeks...does anyone have any ideas?